# Could not upload actions VE logging

Tags: java, android

Running my app in Android N sometimes make a crash, other Android version always normally.

Below is the output from the console:

```
 E/ActionVeLoggingWorker(24604): Could not upload actions VE logging
 E/ActionVeLoggingWorker(24604): com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.exception.GsaIOException: Error code: 262160
 E/ActionVeLoggingWorker(24604):    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.io.a.b(AbstractLogEntry.java:130)
 E/ActionVeLoggingWorker(24604):    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.search.core.k.d.a(AsyncHttpEngine.java:117)
 E/ActionVeLoggingWorker(24604):    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.search.core.k.d$1.call(AsyncHttpEngine.java:2047)
 E/ActionVeLoggingWorker(24604):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
 E/ActionVeLoggingWorker(24604):    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.search.core.k.z$1.run(TaskRunnerScheduledExecutor.java:41)
 E/ActionVeLoggingWorker(24604):    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428)
 E/ActionVeLoggingWorker(24604):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
 E/ActionVeLoggingWorker(24604):    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.af.run(TaskRunnerFutureTask.java:122)
 E/ActionVeLoggingWorker(24604):    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.aq.run(ThrottlingExecutor.java:139)
 E/ActionVeLoggingWorker(24604):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
 E/ActionVeLoggingWorker(24604):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
 E/ActionVeLoggingWorker(24604):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
 E/ActionVeLoggingWorker(24604):    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.aa$1.run(GsaThreadFactory.java:104)
```